# Send cloud to device messages from Azure Function to device via IoT hub

Tags: javascript, azure, azure-functions, azure-iot-hub

Could you help me with the Java code which I use in a Function App?

IoT Hub which built endpoint is used as an IoT Hub(event hub) for a Function App is receiving telemetry from a device. By the following function, I extract values from the message received, process them and put in a CosmoDsB once the IoT Hub build endpoint has gotten a message from the device! 
**The main problem is that i need to send every processed value of  the "totalLevel" variable back to the device via IoT Hub.**
Once again : the entire structure is an "OPC server (MQTT)" <-/-> "IoT Hub" -"build endpoint IoT Hub" - "Function APP" -> back to the device.

[C2D](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NigfE.jpg)

I have not found any simple example how to do this in Java as an addition to the
 existing function. Does anybody know any easy way to do this?

I found these examples but don't have enough skills to modify it.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/azure/iot-hub/quickstart-send-telemetry-java
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-java-java-c2d

thank you in advance

---

```
module.exports = function (context, IoTHubMessages) {
  context.log(`JavaScript eventhub trigger function called for message array: ${IoTHubMessages}`);

  IoTHubMessages.forEach(message => {
    context.log(`Processed message: ${message}`);
  });

  context.done();
};

module.exports = function (context, IoTHubMessages) {
context.log(`JavaScript eventhub trigger function called for message array: 
${IoTHubMessages}`);

var count = 0;
var totalLevel = 0.0;
var totalHumidity = 0.0;
var deviceId = "";

IoTHubMessages.forEach(message => {
    context.log(`Processed message: ${message}`);
    count++;
    totalLevel = message.L1 + message.L2 + message.L3;
    RestartPLC = message.L4;
    deviceId = message.deviceId;
});

var output = {
    "deviceId": deviceId,
    "PLC_Restart_state": RestartPLC,
  //  "measurementsCount": count,
    "gemessener Gesamtabfluss, mm": totalLevel
    //"averageHumidity": totalHumidity/count
};

context.log(`Output content: ${output}`);

context.bindings.outputDocument = output;

context.done();
};
```

Comment: Your code looks like Javascript but the example link you posted are for Java. So which one of the two are you using?

Comment: If you are using Javascript, look here for examples for C2D https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-node-node-c2d#send-a-cloud-to-device-message